# SOLID principle Violation

Tags: php, solid-principles

I have a class 'Image' which has 3 methods `crop()` , `resize()` and `convert()` .

Does it violate Single Responsibility Principle ?

Should I split them into different class ?

```
class Image{ 
     public function crop() {}
     public function resize() {}
     public function convert() {}
}
```

Comment: Don't think so, it's pretty common to have image objects with appropriate methods to alter the image.

Answer (score 1):

**I like to consider that the SOLID principles to be similar to the Pirate Code in that they are "more like guidelines than actual rules"**, especially when it comes to the single responsibility rule.

I see no real reason to make a CopyImage class and a ResizeImage class and a CropImage class.  It makes sense to group these items together since they are all related to manipulating the image.

If you follow the Single Responsibility Principle too explicitly you will end up with a CropLeftSide class, CropRightSide class... etc.

That being said, I would split these methods up if they used different image libraries or drastically different methods to accomplish the result. For example: if you use the ImageMagick library to crop and resize images but used something completely different for copying the image then I would split up those methods accordingly.  This way if you change your method for copying the image the class that resizes and crops does not change.

Answer (score 0):

> Robert Martin defines a responsibility as a reason to change, and concludes that a class or module should have one, and only one, reason to be changed (i.e. rewritten).

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle

The only way your class would need to rewritten was if the way you handle images changes. Therefor it would never violate single responsibility pattern.

```
class Image{ 
....

public function sendImageMail(){}
}
```

If the image class had for example an method to send the image by email, you would violate this principle, due to it having two reasons to change, both the way you handle images, but also if you needed to change the email structure or format. To not violate the single responsibility principle the mail method would be moved to another class.

Comment: Since My class has three methods i.e crop() , resize() and convert() , now it has 3 reasons to change according to SRP definition. So should that be considered violating SRP ? or I am not understanding ? I am new to SOLID

Comment: With that argument all classes with multiple methods have 3 reasons to change. If you implemented the class based on how a jpg image acts, you will only have one reason to change the class and that is if the way you handle jpg images changes. Simarily http://image.intervention.io/ php library has implemented it in a similar way.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I would say it definitely does violate a number of principles:

**S**RP - yes, because the class keeps information about the image, manipulates it, converts to other formats, that’s lots of code

**O**pen/closed - yes, because you cannot add new functionality (new manipulations, new conversion formats) without modifying the class

**L**iskov substitution, **I**nterface segregation, **D**ependendy injection - does not apply

I would totally drop this class in favor of built in [SplFileObject](http://php.net/manual/en/class.splfileobject.php) and create an interface for the manipulation part

```
public function manipulate(\SplFileObject $file): void
```

and the conversion part:

```
public function convert(\SplFileObject $file): \SplFileObject
```

Comment: That is just making OOD imperitive. If you look at how Intervention is doing it, is close to op's answer http://image.intervention.io/

Comment: That doesn’t make Intervention a piece of well written OO code.

Comment: Agreed but the design showed above is better than a service class approach, if formats is of the concern let the function return a new class that handle the formats.